# Matlab: select submatrix from matrix by certain criteria

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, indexing, submatrix

I have a matrix A

```
A=[f magic(10)]
    A=

931142103          92          99           1           8          15          67          74          51          58          40
931142103          98          80           7          14          16          73          55          57          64          41
931142103           4          81          88          20          22          54          56          63          70          47
459200101          85          87          19          21           3          60          62          69          71          28
459200101          86          93          25           2           9          61          68          75          52          34
459200101          17          24          76          83          90          42          49          26          33          65
459200101          23           5          82          89          91          48          30          32          39          66
37833100          79           6          13          95          97          29          31          38          45          72
37833100          10          12          94          96          78          35          37          44          46          53
37833100          11          18         100          77          84          36          43          50          27          59
```

The first column are firm codes. The rest columns are firms' data, with each row referring to the firm in Column 1 in a given year. Notice that years may not be balance for every firms. 
I would like to subtract sub-matrices according to the first column. For instance, for `A(1:3,2:11)` for 931142103:

```
 A(1:3,2:11)

ans =

    92    99     1     8    15    67    74    51    58    40
    98    80     7    14    16    73    55    57    64    41
     4    81    88    20    22    54    56    63    70    47
```

Same as `459200101` (which would be `A(4:7,2:11)`) and `A(8:10,2:11)` for `37833100.`

I get a sense that the code should like this:

```
  indices=find(A(:,1));
    obs=size(A(:,1));
    for i=1:obs,
        if i==indices(i ??)
            A{i}=A(??,2:11);
        end
    end
```

I have difficulties in indexing these complicated codes: `459200101` and `37833100` in order to gather them together. And how can I write the rows of my submatrix `A{i}`?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach with [`arrayfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) -

```
%// Get unique entries from first column of A and keep the order 
%// with 'stable' option i.e. don't sort
unqA1 = unique(A(:,1),'stable') 

%// Use arrayfun to select each such submatrix and store as a cell 
%// in a cell array, which is the final output
outA = arrayfun(@(n) A(A(:,1)==unqA1(n),:),1:numel(unqA1),'Uni',0)
```

Or this -

```
[~,~,row_idx] = unique(A(:,1),'stable')
outA = arrayfun(@(n) A(row_idx==n,:),1:max(row_idx),'Uni',0)
```

Finally, you can verify results with a call to `celldisp(outA)`

Comment: @NicoleLeung Yes, `arrayfun` is really handy in situations like these where cell arrays are needed! Consider accepting the solution that worked best for you? Read more about accepting solutions [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: @NicoleLeung Appreciate the effort! :)

Answer (score 3):

If values in column 1 always appear grouped (as in your example), you can use [`mat2cell`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) as follows:

```
result = mat2cell(A, diff([0; find(diff(A(:,1))); size(A,1)]));
```

If they don't, just sort the rows of `A` according to column 1 before applying the above:

```
A = sortrows(A,1);
result = mat2cell(A, diff([0; find(diff(A(:,1))); size(A,1)]));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the results internally not being ordered, you can use `accumarray` for this:

```
[~,~,I] = unique(A(:,1),'stable');
partitions = accumarray(I, 1:size(A,1), [], @(I){A(I,2:end)});
```